# Convert linux symlink to osx symlink

Tags: osx, symlink

I have transferred a folder from a linux machine to a macbook pro with osx 10.9,
now I am having trouble with the symlinks in this folder (lots of them).
In linux if I do `vi link2file.txt`, it has the same effect as
`vi file.txt`, but in osx, it shows something like this:

```
IntxLNKh�t�m�l�_�t�e�x�.�s�n�i�p�
```

Why is this happening and is there a fast method to fix this?
To recreate all the symlinks by hand would be a PITA.

Comment: how did you transferred the folder from linux to macbook?

Comment: First copied them to a hard drive, then copy from the hard drive to macbook. Oh my god, the hard drive is NTFS, that might be the root of evil!

Comment: just create a `tar -cvf yourfolder.tar ./folder` then transfer yourfolder.tar and then on your mac `tar -xvf yourfolder.tar` to untar archive

Comment: OSX supports the same symbolic links as other unix variants such as Linux. The problem is probably related to NTFS support on either the Linux side or the OSX side. In fact it looks like they've been transformed to Windows shortcuts (which are almost, but not quite, entirely unlike symlinks). Do you want to transfer the symlinks again, or do you want to convert the shortcuts (if that's what they are) into symbolic links? Show us the output of `ls -l link2file.txt` on one of these, and the output of `od -t x1 link2file.txt`.

Comment: Probably osx's fault, I have done this before between linux machines and didn't notice anything wrong. Never mind, I just transferred everything through ssh and it's perfect.

Comment: As it's solved, you could answer your own question, so it does not stay unanswered forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to osx's lack of support for NTFS. I just transferred everything all over again through ssh, and it worked perfectly.